# Having trouble with an iterative solution of a binary tree to obtain sum of paths equaling a target sum

Tags: javascript, algorithm, iteration, binary-tree, depth-first-search

The objective is as described in this problem:

You are given a binary tree in which each node contains an integer value.
Find the number of paths that sum to a given value.
The path does not need to start or end at the root or a leaf, but it must go downwards (traveling only from parent nodes to child nodes).
The tree has no more than 1,000 nodes and the values are in the range -1,000,000 to 1000,000.

Example:
root = [10,5,-3,3,2,null,11,3,-2,null,1], sum = 8

```
          10
         /  \
        5   -3
       / \    \
      3   2   11
     / \   \
    3  -2   1
```

Return 3. The paths that sum to 8 are:

1. 5 -> 3
2. 5 -> 2 -> 1
3. -3 -> 11

I have written the following code which I want to solve iteratively, not using recursion, however, I am unable to get the correct count and can't find the flaw in my logic.

```
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
}


const pathSum = (root, sum) => {
    if (!root) return 0
    let totals = [root]
    let queue = [root]
    let count = 0
    let current

    while (queue.length) {
        current = queue.shift()
        if (current.val === sum) count++
        for (let s of totals) {
            if (s.val + current.val === sum) count++
        }
        if (current.left) queue.push(current.left), totals.push(current.left)
        if (current.right) queue.push(current.right), totals.push(current.right)
    }
    return count
}

const tree = new TreeNode(10)
tree.left = new TreeNode(5)
tree.right = new TreeNode(-3)

tree.left.left = new TreeNode(3)
tree.left.right = new TreeNode(2)
tree.left.right = new TreeNode(2)
tree.right.right = new TreeNode(11)

tree.left.left.left = new TreeNode(3)
tree.left.left.right = new TreeNode(-2)
tree.left.right.right = new TreeNode(1)

console.log(pathSum(tree, 8))
```

Would appreciate if anyone has suggestions to make the code work iteratively.

Comment: Just a level order traversal is not the answer to this algorithm. At each node you need to look for a path which starts with that node and has path sum equal to desired target. You would need a stack if it needs to be iterative

Comment: I was using two queues to get the path sum, but am still unable to figure out the logic required.  Totals being the second queue to check if the sum of the current value and the child node value gives me the target sum.